# Parsing csv file to class getter methods with opencsv

Tags: java, arraylist, opencsv

I am trying to pass a csv file using opencsv.The csv file has three columns (,). How do i parse each line to my arraylist with the respective values? See code below.

```
public class Customer { 

    private String accNum;  
    private String fName;   
    private String lName;   

    public Customer(String accNum, String fName, String lName) {        

    this.accNum = accNum;
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
     }

    //getters & setters
    ...
}

public class CustomerList{

public void getCustList(File file) throws IOException {     
    List <Customer> custList = new ArrayList <Customer>();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader (new FileReader (file));
    String [] header = reader.readNext();       
    List<String[]> cList = reader.readAll();

    for (int i =0 ; i < cList.size(); i++)
    {
        String[] line = cList.get(i); //not sure how to do this
        for (String list: line)
        {
            custList.add( new Customer (list));// constructor takes three arguments
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda like a JDBC ResultSet.

```
List <Customer> custList = new ArrayList <Customer>();
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader (new FileReader (file));
String[] header = reader.readNext();
if (header == null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("No header");
}

String[] row;
while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null)
{
    if (row.length != 3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected number of entries: " + row.length);
    }
    custList.add(new Customer(row[0], row[1], row[2]));
}
```

Comment: You can do it as mentioned in the answer below, but I recommend iterating over the rows with readNext as I outlined here. That way you aren't forced to load the whole CSV file into memory. Instead, you can process it as a stream. It depends on whether you expect a large number of rows.

Comment: I used you method it works. I had to remove the 'if (row.length != 3)' for now though. I failed to mentioned that the csv file isn't consistent. There are a few scenarios with no lastname resulting in two commas at end of line. Or no first name, lines may or may not have a comma at the end. Because of this it gets a little more complicated. You are right iterating over the rows is better since the csv files have more that a 100,000 lines. Thanks John much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the for loop into something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < cList.size(); i++) {
    String[] line = cList.get(i);
    custList.add(new Customer(line[0], line[1], line[2]));
}
```

Assuming, of course, that the columns are in the order accNum, fName, lName.

Comment: They are in that order however not necessarily consistent. some lines may not contain one of the elements resulting in ,, together etc.. see. It doesn't seem opencsv can handle these occurrences as i would want it to.